# Разрешить нажать на кнопку при редакции InputField Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity3d, input, button

Здравствуйте.
Я пишу прорамму для логина пользователя на Unity С#.
Вот окно в спокойном состоянии
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Окно когда InputField редактируется
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как я понял событие onendedit() срабатывает при нажатии за пределами InputField. В моем случае это событие возвращает окно в исходное состояние вне зависимости произошел ли клик по кнопке или нет, но мне надо условие: при нажатии на кнопку в состоянии редактирования должно выполниться событие onclick() у кнопки а потом только вернуться в исходное состояние то есть подождать пока не выполниться событие onclick(). Вызывать сам метод onclick() нежелательно так как таких окон много и у каждого разные кнопки у которых предназначения и методы обработки при нажатии лежат в разных скриптах поэтому они висят в событии button onclick(), то есть как заставить программу ждать пока событие кнопки не обработаеться и только потом вернуть окно в исходное состояние?

Comment: Не полагайся на дефолтные события, пиши свои

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо вопрос закрыт.

Решение оказалось ну слишком уж простым. Опишу решение в кратце:

Я сделал проверку совпадают ли координаты мыши и кнопки при клике, если да то ничего не делаем и уже в самом событии onclick() кнопки вызывается метод возврата окна в исходное состояние, а если нет то просто вызываем метод возврата в исходное состояние.